# Apache RewriteRule: Is the pattern "." a special case?

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have seen *numerous* RewriteRule examples along the lines of the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The intention here is that URIs that are not backed by a real file will be handled by a CMS, hooked into via /index.php.  WordPress, for example, uses this technique in its [standard(*?*) .htaccess file](http://rogerkar.blogspot.com/2009/04/wordpress-htaccess-file-explained.html).

However, the regexp doesn't make any sense.  Without getting into a discussion of what subject-string is being matched against (but see "What is matched?" in the official Apache RewriteRule docs), the regexp `.` should only match **the very first character**!   However, it behaves identically to `.*`, that is, matching the **entire** subject-string.  Setting `RewriteLogLevel 5`, I get the same results and log entries for `.` and `.*`.

I can only conclude that a RewriteRule with the pattern `.` is special-cased and matches the whole string (a la `.*`), rather than processed via the RegExp engine as-is.  However, I haven't seen this documented anywhere.  Is the documentation deficient, or *am I just totally missing something?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, duh....I hate when I realize I'm just being lame.

I'm approaching mod-rewrite from the mindset of a programmer.   In every regexp library I know of, substitution replaces only the *matched part* of the subject-string.   So e.g.

```
$ perl
$hello = "hello";
$hello =~ s/lo/p/;
print "$hello\n";
^D
```

Displays

```
help
```

In mod-rewrite, however, we aren't *manipulating* the string.  If the URI is matched at all, we *completely* replace it with the Substitution.  Therefore, a mere match (".") is enough to replace the *entire string* with /index.php.

The [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) sort of state this, but not so forcefully as to correct someone who's in the wrong headspace:

> The Substitution of a rewrite rule is
>   the string that replaces the original
>   URL-path that was matched by Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

By default, regular expressions match the input string anywhere.
Your assumption that `.` should only match the very first character is false: it will match **any** character, the first one, the last one, the 24th char, it doesn't matter: any non-empty string will match. `.*` has a subtle difference: it will match any string, even zero length ones.

To get the behavior you thought, use `^` (match at the beginning of the string) and `$` (match at the end).

Summary:

`.` will match any string having at least one character
`.*` will match any string, even empty
`^.$` will match only a one character long string
`^.*$` will match any string in single-line mode, or any line in multi-line mode

Comment: Thank you, Julien.  Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my question.  When I wrote "the regexp . should only match the very first character!", I didn't mean that I _desired_ it to only match the first character (on the contrary, to work it must match the whole string).  Nor did I mean that _syntactically_ "." only ever matches the first character of its subject string (as in "^.").  Rather I meant that _in practice_ when the pattern "." is applied to the string "abcd", the match is "a".  I take it as a given here that we are *not* doing s///g global matching (for those accustomed to Perl syntax).